# Por que aparece a mensagem "Não acessar array superglobal diretamente"?

Tags: php, sanitize

Como posso utilizar a array `$_GET` sem que dê esse problema (Netbeans), já que mesmo quando eu utilizo dessa forma dá erro:

```
$var = isset($_GET['variavel'])?filter_var($_GET['variavel'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT): false;
```

Comment: Erro ou ele sugere alguma coisa?

Comment: É Warning só, não é erro. Pode usar tranquilamente.

Comment: qual versão do seu php?

Comment: Utilizo a versão 7

Comment: Qual erro/warn que ocorre?